# Fill table with php

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

i need to fill a table with mysql data, but i want to add a new line for every 3 mysql records.

filling the table its easy. but how do i tell to add a `<tr>` to every 3 records??

so far i have this:

```
 <table width="30%" border="0">
  <tbody>
  <tr>
   <?php if($totalRows_rsSdk>0){
       do{
    ?>     
<td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="sdkcheck" id="sdkcheck<?php echo $row_rsSdk['id']; ?>"/><label for="sdkcheck<?php echo $row_rsSdk['id']; ?>" class="css-label2 radGroup3"><?php echo $row_rsSdk['nome']; ?></label></td>
 <td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="Images/sdk-icons/<?php echo $row_rsSdk['icon']; ?>" height="70"></td>

    <?php } while ($row_rsSdk = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSdk));} ?>
     </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi, this may help you, I asked a similar question a few years ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10977868/php-tables-consisting-of-3-rows-loaded-from-sql-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<table width="30%" border="0">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <?php if($totalRows_rsSdk>0){
            $counter = 0;
            do{
                ?>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" name="sdkcheck" id="sdkcheck<?php echo $row_rsSdk['id']; ?>"/><label for="sdkcheck<?php echo $row_rsSdk['id']; ?>" class="css-label2 radGroup3"><?php echo $row_rsSdk['nome']; ?></label></td>
                <td align="center" valign="middle"><img src="Images/sdk-icons/<?php echo $row_rsSdk['icon']; ?>" height="70"></td>

            <?php
                $blockSize = 3;
                $counter++;
                if ($counter >= $blockSize) {
                    $counter = 0;
            ?>
                </tr>
                <tr>
            <?php
                }
            } while ($row_rsSdk = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsSdk));} ?>
            <?php echo str_repeat('<td></td>',($blockSize-$counter)); ?>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yes, you can use it, but topicstarted doesn't. That's why I post answer in topicstarter style. And not for "form", for HTML templater's.

Comment: @ranonymus00 Well, you should use alternate syntax when working with templates

Comment: Why do you think, that this is wrong? You have any PSR-* specs, where someone write that you can't use PHP common style in templates?

Comment: That PSR-* is not officially published yet, its in drafts I saw on google groups somewhere. Look, what you do `$counter = 0; do{ ?>` is kinda Word-Press style. Look any decent framework doc, why they recommend and do use alternate syntax

Comment: May be topicstarter use wordpress, to you think about this?